# Backup, save, download all questions and answers for individual users

Tags: support, data-explorer

[Why can't I run data queries on the Math Site?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1410), [How do I know I won't lose all my work in math.SE?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9148) say
there are data dumps for math.se. But how do I download only the data for one user? This data includes all the text as people typed, right? Ergo I will have the `$ mathjax $`?

I don't want to download the data dump for the whole website. I want to backup and save all questions and answers for users for offline use. I'm not fantastic with computer programming.

By the agency of 127.0.9.6's answer, I question if you can download all your questions, answers, and comments in one query? I see 2 now.

http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/38557/get-all-your-posts-and-comments is for your questions and comments.

http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/172383/all-answers-by-a-user-with-questions is for your answers.

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 6):

One of several queries that could be used for this purpose is [Get all your posts and comments](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/38557/get-all-your-posts-and-comments). The last column indicates the type of post: 1 = question, 2 = answer, 3 = comment. 
For your convenience, here it the query [with your UserId pre-filled](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/38557/get-all-your-posts-and-comments). You do not need to create a Data Explorer account; queries can be run anonymously (you'll just get a CaptCha to solve).

However, downloading answers without matching questions is probably not very useful. Here is a query to get [your answers with the questions to which they refer](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/172383/all-answers-by-a-user-with-questions).

Keep in mind that Data Explorer imports data from the site weekly (on weekends). So your very recent posts will not appear in the results.

Comment: thanks. +upvote. i want to check if you can download all your questions, answers, and comments in one query? Please apprise me in your answer?

Comment: Isn't there a limit on maximal number of results returned by a SEDE query? (IIRC someone mentioned the existence of such limit on this meta. I searched a little on meta.SO, but did not find what the limit is. Although I do not know whether such number of answers and comments can be realistically written by one user.)

Comment: I found it: It was mentioned [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12131/distribution-of-time-to-first-answer-in-mathstackexchange#comment47327_12131) that there is a limit of of 50000 results for one query.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes, a query returns at most 50000 rows. That ought to be enough for anybody™: e.g., Brian M. Scott posted <9000 answers and <15000 comments. Also, a query can be modified to return only posts within a given time interval; then one can run it several times and merge the results in a spreadsheet. One can download *all* posts in this way, if one wishes.

Comment: Even Jon Skeet of Stack Overflow fame has <30000 answers so far; though he does have >50000 comments.